# Problems with positioning Safari’s music player

Tags: html, css

I’m making a small website to host my music, where each section has its own layout. My problem is with this specific page - https://terramsc.github.io/vault/for-zofia.html

I’ve decided to position an MP3 player on the bottom of the site, in a fixed div stuck to the bottom. It looks OK everywhere, except Safari mobile browser. It appears cut and I don’t know how am I supposed to fix it.

````
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title></title>
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Inter:wght@100;200;300;400;500;600;700;800;900&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Press+Start+2P&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
  </head>

  <style>
    /* GET RID OFF TUMBLR BS */

    #tumblr_controls,
    .controls {
      display: none !important;
    }

    #tumblr_controls {
      display: none;
    }

    iframe:first-child {
      display: none !important;
    }

    iframe:nth-child(2) {
      display: none;
    }

    .app-cta-button {
      opacity: 0 !important;
    }

    .tmblr-iframe--app-cta-button {
      display: none !important;
    }

    .tmblr-iframe-compact .tmblr-iframe--unified-controls {
      display: none;
    }

    #search {
      display: none;
    }

    /* HTML & BODY */

    html,
    body {
      margin: 0;
      background-color: #B16791;
    }

    html,
    body,
      {
      font-family: 'Inter', sans-serif;
    }

    /* MAIN CENTERED DIV WITH A PIC */

    .outer {
      display: table;
      position: absolute;
      top: 0;
      left: 0;
      height: 100%;
      width: 100%;
    }

    .middle {
      display: table-cell;
      vertical-align: middle;
    }

    .inner {
      margin-left: auto;
      margin-right: auto;
      max-width: 600px;
      width: 100%;
      text-align: center;
      color: white;
      /* Whatever width you want */
    }

    /* GO BACK BUTTON */

    input[type=button] {
      margin: 20px 0px 0px 20px;
      padding: 0;
      position: fixed;
      height: 100px;
      width: 100px;
      border-radius: 100px;
      background: #B16791;
      border: 1px solid #B16791;
      font-weight: 1000;
      font-size: 48px;
      background-image: url("https://i.imgur.com/mojAVpi.gif");
      background-repeat: no-repeat;
      background-position: 50% 50%;
      background-size: 100%;
      z-index: 99;
    }

    input[type=button]:hover {
      cursor: pointer;
    }

    /* SOMGS */

    #somgs {
      font-family: 'Press Start 2P', cursive;
      color: white;
      position: fixed;
      bottom: 20px;
      left: 20px;
      width: 600px;
    }

    #somgs2 {
      font-family: 'Press Start 2P', cursive;
      color: white;
      position: fixed;
      display: none;
      bottom: 40px;
      left: 40px;
      right: 40px;
      font-size: 36px;
    }

    audio {
      border-radius: 100px;
      right: 0;
      width: 100%;
    }

    /* OTHER */

    #top_text {
      font-family: 'Press Start 2P', cursive;
      color: white;
      width: 100%;
      text-align: center;
      padding-top: 20px;
    }

    @media only screen and (max-width: 1000px) {
      .subtitle {
        font-size: 42px;
      }

      input[type=button] {
        height: 140px;
        width: 140px;
        cursor: pointer;
      }

      #somgs {
        display: none;
      }

      audio {
        border-radius: 100px;
        width: 100%;
      }

      #somgs {
        display: none;
      }

      #somgs2 {
        display: initial;
        left: 0;
        right: 0;
        padding: 0px 40px 0px 40px;
      }

      #top_text {
        padding-top: 72px;
        font-size: 36px;
      }

    }

  </style>

  <script type="text/javascript">
    document.getElementById("button").onclick = function() {
      location.href = "https://terramsc.github.io/vault/index.html";
    };

  </script>

  <body>

    <div id="button"><input type="button" value="" onclick="location.href = 'https://terramsc.github.io/vault/';"></div>

    <div class="outer">
      <div class="middle">
        <div class="inner">
          <img src="https://i.imgur.com/nc24BBo.gif" width="100%">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div id="somgs">
      <p>"I couldn't say goodbye"</p>
      <p>v0.1 - 17.04.2022</p>
      <audio controls>
        <source src="https://drive.google.com/file/d/1eFnqeF0wmRhAXwG8UrYWWpYgiyteEbnu" type="audio/mpeg" /></audio>
    </div>

    <div id="somgs2">
      <p>"I couldn't say goodbye"</p>
      <p>v0.1 - 17.04.2022</p>
      <audio controls>
        <source src="https://drive.google.com/file/d/1eFnqeF0wmRhAXwG8UrYWWpYgiyteEbnu" type="audio/mpeg" /></audio>
    </div>

    <div id="top_text">
      sleep tight
    </div>

  </body>

</html>```


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/xeFLt.jpg
````

Comment: A picture of how it looks for me - https://imgur.com/a/xdjMqNt

Comment: The issue may have something to do with the way the vertical viewport value is calculated on mobile Safari and because of the bottom tab the part of your website cuts off. The goal is to set the height to 100% all the way up to `html` element. Therefore, try to set `height: 100%` to `html` and `body` elements

Comment: Fixing padding and using *box-sizing: border-box;* helped.